# How to stop animation and turn off the delay time in superfish menu?

Tags: 7, navigation

I created a superfish menu block and set the animation speed at fast and delay time to 0. Still it taking time to open the child menus. I disabled the animation using [this article](http://emerging.commons.gc.cuny.edu/2013/05/making-a-superfish-menu-faster-by-removing-animation/) but still it taking time to open the menu. I want to open the child menu just when user hover on the parent menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding custom js did the trick.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish({
       delay: 0,
       autoArrows: false,
       speed: 'fast',
       disableHI: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you tell me where can i put this code please?

Comment: You can add in theme, in custom module anywhere you want..